# Firestore/Swift 4: Check username exists?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand where i may be going wrong with the following code. I have tried to look up a way to check if the `users` collection contains a string within one of it's documents within a `username` field.

Structure looks something like this

```
#users(collection)
    #userID(document)
        #name:String
        #email:String
        #username:String
    #userID(document)
        #name:String
        #email:String
        #username:String
```

What i am trying to check is if within `users`, and within any `document,` does the string exist in the `username` field. Found a possible solution to this question (among others) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971814/firebase-querying-for-unique-username-swift) by calling a function to query for the username.

I created the function in an extension:

```
extension UITextField {

    func checkUsername(username: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
        let usernameRef = Database.database().reference()
        usernameRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                completion(true)
            }
            else {
                completion(false)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

and called it on the text field within textFieldDidEndEditing so it can perform the check upon the user attempting to claim a username.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if activeField == usernameField {
        textField.checkUsername(username: usernameField.text!) { isExist in
            if isExist {
                print("Username exists")
            } else {
                print("Username does not exist")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, this always returns `'Username does not exist'` to the console, even when the username does exist.

There is currently 1 username within the database called `test`, so attempting to enter test should return `'Username exists'` and entering `testtwo` should return `'Username does not exist'`.

What can i be missing here? I am assuming its not querying the database correctly?

Comment: You tagged the question as Cloud Firestore, but are using the Firebase Realtime Database in your code. The two databases are quite different, so which one are you using?

Comment: Firestore :) I assume that's where it's going wrong if i am attempting to check a realtime database instead of Firestore database.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely won't work. Be sure to check the Firestore documentation on getting documents, here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Thanks! Just taking a look now to see what i need to amend? On that note, would it better to place all the usernames into a separate collection called 'usernames' when the user is created, so i would only need to query the documents in the collection, rather than query each document individually for a field which has the username?

Comment: Performance wise that would be pretty much the same, so I'd go for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Frank for pointing out i was calling the Realtime Database rather than Firestore. Updated my code to return a `true` or `false` value when checking documents for anything stored within `'username'` and thought i would share my updated code if anyone else is attempting to check `'usernames'` within their Firestore DB.

Created an extension on the UITextField which is called when i require checking a username is available:

```
func checkUsername(field: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let collectionRef = db.collection("users")
    collectionRef.whereField("username", isEqualTo: field).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting document: \(err)")
        } else if (snapshot?.isEmpty)! {
            completion(false)
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                if document.data()["username"] != nil {
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the `UITextField` `textDidEndEditing`, i call the function is the active field is the username field:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if activeField == usernameField {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            textField.checkUsername(field: textField.text!) { (success) in
                if success == true {
                    print("Username is taken")
                    // Perform some action
                } else {
                    print("Username is not taken")
                    // Perform some action
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This then returns `'Username is taken'` if i attempt to enter a username that exists in any of the documents `username` field, or `'Username is not taken'` if nothing is found.

If anyone has any feedback to improve the code or any questions, let me know. I'll happily update for reference. :)